# Tooltip-trigger : focus ? On focus uib tooltip does not show message?

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

Hi I was just going through `uib-tooltip` and i saw `tooltip-trigger`. On focus its not working is there something wrong ?

Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eA95j7IsfGp3nwAK82RJ?p=preview). Seems like the directive itself is not providing the functionality. I just tested it on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cxQJ5YzPyU5cilyeh8kq?p=preview). The issue was the placement of the tooltip was set to appear to the right, but since your input spans the entire width of the view it was getting hidden.

Modifying the tooltip placement to 'bottom' now enables the tooltip to appear on focus.

```
<input type="text" value="Click me!" uib-tooltip="See? Now click away..." tooltip-trigger="'focus'" tooltip-placement="bottom" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: it does not in modal.

Comment: add a plunkr. most likely you need to set the append to body property